# How to change the keyphrase in the pass program without reinitializing a pass store from scratch

Tags: password, passwd, password-store

I'm using the `pass` application which I find really handy. I want to change the keyphrase (mother password). I had a look at the man page [there](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/) but i'm not sure what to do. Do I have to use the `init` command?. Is it possible to change the passphrase without reinitializing a pass store from scratch? If yes which exact command should be done?

I tried the following from the comments:

Many thank for your comment

So I did the following:

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys

/Users/user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------
sec   ....
      ....
uid           [ultimate] firstnamelastname <firstnamelastname@mail.com>
ssb   ...

sec   ....
      ....
uid           [ultimate] Firstname Lastname <firstnamelastname@mail.com>
ssb   ...
```

Note the email adress is the same

There is no file ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf. I created a one and wrote `default-key firstnamelastname` in it and source it but got

```
gpg.conf:1: command not found: default-key
```

Comment: 1. there's something seriously broken with your system or your gnupg installation if using `default-key` in your gpg.conf causes a `command not found` error.   This should not happen, it's like it's trying to source the gpg.conf as a script or execute it rather than parse it as a config file.  2. you should use the key fingerprint with `default-key`, not the name or email address. The fingerprint will be the long string of hex digits immediately after the `sec` line. Unlike names or email addresses, this is unique to the key-pair.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @cas. So in my case , the key fingerprint would be `firstnamelastname` correct? Do you think that it can have to do with the fact that I am on MacOS?

Comment: No, it would be the long string of hex digits (e.g. "3F93BFC18E47EC42E3A2C20218D52ABC8E47EC42" as a made up example).   This will be on the line immediately after the `sec` line when you run `gpg --list-secret-keys`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pass` uses [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/) to encrypt your password store.  To change the passphrase for `pass`, you need to change the passphrase for your `gpg` key.

e.g.

```
gpg --change-passphrase user-id
```

Comment: Many thanks @cas! May I ask you how and where this information can be found?

Comment: Well actually @cas I did the command and could a keyphrase and I thought it worked, but now I still have to give the old keyphrase to have access to the passwords as if nothing had changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you use a different gpg key for pass? If so, you have to change the passphrase for the key used by pass (i ran into this issue myself several years ago when I generated a new key).   As for where the info can be found, in the pass docs - it clearly states that it uses gpg to handle encryption (and git for revision history).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @cas. what do you mean by key? is it the same as the user-id? If the key is neither the user-id nore the keyphrase, what is it and do you have an Idea about how I could troubleshoot the next step?

Comment: by "key", I actually meant "key pair" - a public and a private key.   A key pair is associated with a user-id (typically a name, or an email address, etc. it's an identifier that doesn't have to be unique).   `gpg` can manage the crypto key pairs for multiple user ids at the same time (e.g. if you have multiple separate and unrelated email addresses, they can each have their own key)....and it can manage multiple key pairs for the same id (e.g. an old and a new key for the same address. or a key you use for work, one you use for a particular project, and one you use for personal stuff)

Comment: There are command line options for gpg to tell it which key to use for the current command.  Otherwise it will use the default key, or the first one it finds that matches the user-id.   If you have multiple keys, you can tell it which key to use as the default with the `default-key xxxxxxxxxxx` option in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.    You can list your secret keys (i.e. the ones it knows the private key for, the ones it is managing for YOU) with `gpg --list-secret-keys`

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @cas. I tried the commands you wrote in your comment in the edited question bust still cannot change the passphrase. Do you have an idea of what I should do next?

Comment: I finally could change it. I think the trouble was related to the fact that I have 2 user-id (don't ask my why...)